# Mistake in recursive algorithm

Tags: recursion, algorithm

I am new to Wolfram, and I am trying to make a recursive Archimedes algorithm in Wolfram.

I read documentation and I tried to run this code

```
RSolve[{ a[n + 1] == 2^n Sqrt[2 (1 - Sqrt[1 - (a[n]/2^n)^2])], a[1] == 2}, a[n], n] 
Table[a[n] /. First[%], {n, 10}]
```

But instead of a table like if the first line was `RSolve[{a[n] == 2 a[n - 1], a[1] == 1}, a[n], n]` I have lots of errors

```
ReplaceAll::reps: {a[2]==2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[1-Sqrt[Plus[<<2>>]]],a[1]==2} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.
```

Can somebody help me, where is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the recurrence equation has no explicit formula. Hence you get back an unevaluated `RSolve` and the `First` of that is the original recurrence equation and not the formula.

If you change the function from `RSolve` to `RecurrenceTable` then you will directly get the list of solutions.

```
RecurrenceTable[{a[n + 1] == 2^n Sqrt[2 (1 - Sqrt[1 - (a[n]/2^n)^2])], a[1] == 2}, a[n], {n, 10}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve your recursion is to define:

```
a[n_] := a[n] = 2^(n - 1) Sqrt[2 (1 - Sqrt[1 - (a[n - 1]/2^(n - 1))^2])];
a[1] = 2;
```

Then you can get the first 4 values using Table[a[i],{i,4}] or

```
a[#] & /@ Range[4]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, yes, it is working. But still where is a mistake in my code, I thought I did everything the same way as in examples?

Comment: simpler: `Array[a,4]`.

Comment: Or `a /@ Range[4]`.